# Why is pickle crashing my flask server?

Tags: python, flask, pickle

#### The Problem

I am running a server which crashes when I try to pickle a simple, pickleable object.  The server ONLY crashes if debug mode is turned on.  If I remove `debug=True`, the server runs fine.  I was also unable to replicate the bug when I put my code into a single file, as opposed to a package.  Both Python 2.7 and 3.3 exhibited this problem.

The server crashes after a get request is received for the '/' path.  I don't get any feedback about what went wrong or what's going on - the browser page just hangs as if it is loading, forever. Running through the program with a debugger was not helpful.

My suspicion is that pickle is having trouble locating the base class file as a result of the way that flask is automatically reloading the modules, but I do not know how to explore that idea further.

#### The Code

I have a package structured as follows:

```
MyServer
    __init__.py
runserver.py
```

__init__.py:

```
import pickle
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

@app.route('/')
def show_front():
    o = Test('test')
    x = pickle.dumps(o)
    return x

app.run(debug=True)
```

runserver.py:

```
import MyServer
```

Comment: When you say it "crashes", does it give you a traceback? Can you at all identify an error message or line number?

Comment: There is no traceback.  If I try loading the page in a browser, the browser just hangs there.  When I try stepping through with a debugger, the process just stops like it's waiting for something, but I can't tell what.

Answer (score 2):

I used [hanging_threads](https://gist.github.com/niccokunzmann/6038331) to get where the threads are waiting.
This is one line among many:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in wait
    _subprocess.INFINITE)
```

Flask starts a new process that waits and serves the output I guess.
But if it starts a new process that implies that:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

is also executed in the child.

Solution:

1. do not start the app if imported. `app.run(debug=True)` =>

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug=True)
   ```
2. change `runserver.py` to

   ```
   import MyServer
   MyServer.app.run(debug=True)
   ```

Then I got this output:

```
ccopy_reg _reconstructor p0 (cMyServer Test p1 c__builtin__ object p2 Ntp3 Rp4 (dp5 S'name' p6 S'test' p7 sb.
```

Comment: I changed runserver.py as you suggested, and it seems to have fixed the problem.  Surprisingly, everything seemed to be working fine with the exception of pickle.  Do you have any idea why pickle specifically would cause the thread to hang?

Comment: 1st I know that pickle uses `__import__` to load a module for a class. 2nd flask uses subprocess/multiprocessing. But I have no idea but to guess that pickle loads the module not just once maybe?